# What does it mean when a web service is called asynchronous?

Tags: web-services, web

What does it mean when a web service is asynchronous? Is it for a part of the web page which refreshes when it is done??

Comment: It such a loose wording, it means the “thing calling the web service” will “handle the result asynchronously or ‘later, when it is ready’”, with the effect of “not blocking other processing”, such as allowing a user to continue to interact with the webpage.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming) — “Asynchrony .. refers to the occurrence of events (such as making a web request) independent of the main program flow (such as processing user interactions on a web browser) and ways to deal with such events.”

Comment: There is another meaning of an “asynchronous web service”, dealing with the implementation of such and not the asynchrony established by the caller .. such doesn’t seem to be the ask here.